# Dplyr - Error: column '' has unsupported type

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate-functions, dplyr

I have a odd issue when using dplyr on a data.frame to compute the number of missing observations for each group of a character variable. This creates the error "Error: column "" has unsupported type.

To replicate it I have created a subset. The subset rdata file is available here: 
[rdata file including dftest data.frame](http://www.gisintersect.com/dftest.rdata)
First. Using the subset I have provided, the code:

```
dftest %>%
  group_by(file) %>%
  summarise(missings=sum(is.na(v131)))
```

Will create the error:
Error: column 'file' has unsupported type

The str(dftest) returns:

```
'data.frame':   756345 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ file: atomic  bjir31fl.dta bjir31fl.dta bjir31fl.dta bjir31fl.dta ...
  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr 
 $ v131: Factor w/ 330 levels "not of benin",..: 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 9 9 9 ...
```

However, taking a subset of the subset, and running the dplyr command again, will create the expected output.

```
dftest <- dftest[1:756345,]
dftest %>%
  group_by(file) %>%
  summarise(missings=sum(is.na(v131)))
```

The str(dftest) now returns:

```
'data.frame':   756345 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ file: chr  "bjir31fl.dta" "bjir31fl.dta" "bjir31fl.dta" "bjir31fl.dta" ...
 $ v131: Factor w/ 330 levels "not of benin",..: 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 9 9 9 ...
```

Anyone have any suggestions about what might cause this error, and what to do about it. In my original file I have 300 variables, and dplyr states that most of these are of unsupported type.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create `dftest`? I've never seen a data.frame with a column listed as "atomic". It just appears to be an ill-formed data.frame.

Comment: Yes @MrFlick, something is not right. The dftest comes from a data.frame named df, which is the result of appending many STATA file together. However, since some factor labels are of string length 0, I change this to string length 1. Apparently, this code creates the problem:

`for(x in (names(df))){
  print(x)
  dflevels <- levels(df[[x]]) 
  print(dflevels[dflevels==""])
  levels(df[[x]])[levels(df[[x]])==""] <- " "
  df[[x]][df[[x]]==""] <- " "
  df[[x]] <- df[[x]][,drop=TRUE]  
}`

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. You're just trying to replace the zero length labels with a single space? How about just `for(x in names(df)) levels(df[[x]]) <- gsub("^$"," ", levels(df[[x]]))`

Comment: I am unsure why you mean that the code does not make any sense. It is a for loop, going through each variable name, checking if there is a level with length 0. So this code `levels(df[[x]])[levels(df[[x]])==""] <- " "` replaces levels of length "" with a space. Must be done before changing content, or the level will not be "allowed". This code `df[[x]][df[[x]]==""] <- " "`changes the actual value in the factor. This `df[[x]] <- df[[x]][,drop=TRUE]` drops unused levels, which might occur, as the original stata file has more levels than there is in the data.

Comment: I face the same issue each time I read a database from SPSS. 
At the moment, I transform all the factor variables into characters. But is it not an ideal solution I agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with using `filter` when a column of the data frame has an attribute. For example,

```
> df = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
> filter(df, x==3) # Works
  x y
1 3 3
```

Add an attribute to the `x` column. Notice that `str(df)` shows `x` as `atomic` now, and `filter` doesn't work:

```
> attr(df$x, 'width')='broad'
> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: atomic  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..- attr(*, "width")= chr "broad"
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> filter(df, x==3)
Error: column 'x' has unsupported type
```

To make it work, remove the attribute:

```
> attr(df$x, 'width') = NULL
> filter(df, x==3)
  x y
1 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the appropriate solution. I will see if this fixes my issue, and Accept answer.